# Swapping elements of a char array works but swapping elements of a char string leads to core dump

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to perform swap operation as shown in below program, but it seems to crash when I am copying the element b into a (line 3 in swap() method) - this happens if the input is a char string i.e, char *str;  If it is a character array instead (as in char str[];) the swap operation works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
  char tmp;
  tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;       /* crash occurs here */
  *b = tmp;
}

void func(char *a)
{
  swap(a+1, a+2);
}

int main()
{
  char *str = "abc";

  // char str[] = "abc";   /* with this char array, the above swap func works */  

  func(str);
}
```

I think this is related to some C string rules that I seem to be unaware of. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *str = "abc";
```

Above puts the string in the constant data section (also known as .rdata) of the program.As this is treated as constant data, it can not be modified

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

Above puts the string in the stack area of the program, as declared inside the function scope.This data can be modified.

As this is about the storage of string data, you are getting Crash in first declaration.

Comment: ..Thanks. Does it mean the char string (allocated memory in .rdata section) will have global scope (not sure if it would be global or static) if in case it does.

Answer (score 4):

String literals are *read-only*, trying to modify a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*.

Simplest solution? Declare it as an array instead:

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

Comment: Yep. Try `char *str = strdup("abc");` to get a mutatable string.

Comment: @MohammedRaqeeb Remember that `strdup` allocates memory that you need to `free`!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for pointing it out, just went through the man page of strdup(), we indeed need to explicitly free the memory as it is allocated on heap.

Answer (score 0):

'char *str = "abc";'
The above places the abc in read only memory. So it cannot be modified.
'char str[]="abc";' is placed in stack. so it can be modified.